# how to retrieve data from database into label using while loop?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am getting a single entry from database, as i need all my entries to be fetched to my web page here is the code.

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
con.Open();

str = "select * from computer";
com = new SqlCommand(str, con);

SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();

reader.Read();

label1.Text = reader["ComputerName"].ToString();
label2.Text = reader["ComputerIP"].ToString();
label3.Text = reader["os_version"].ToString();
label4.Text = reader["u_name"].ToString();
label5.Text = reader["status"].ToString();
label6.Text = reader["os_bits"].ToString();
label7.Text = reader["nprocessor"].ToString();

reader.Close();
con.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

just use

```
while (reader.Read())
{
// your code to store values in variables
}
reader.Close();// to close the reader
```

reader has all records from db. All you have to do is apply a loop to get all those values in hand.

Here is the reference:
http://csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet/Lesson04

Answer (score 0):

your code should be like this

```
 SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
        con.Open();
        str = "select * from computer";
        com = new SqlCommand(str, con);
        SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();

       while (reader.Read())
{
            label1.Text = reader["ComputerName"].ToString();

            label2.Text = reader["ComputerIP"].ToString();

            label3.Text = reader["os_version"].ToString();

            label4.Text = reader["u_name"].ToString();

            label5.Text = reader["status"].ToString();

            label6.Text = reader["os_bits"].ToString();

            label7.Text = reader["nprocessor"].ToString();
}
        reader.Close();
        con.Close();
```

Comment: I think s/he has a single rows of data from database otherwise better display the data on the gridview @marc_s

Comment: @Marc_s S/he has clearly mentioned ,there will be single row of data